# Odata Post Collection FromBody

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I'm working on rebuilding an API by converting to aspnetcore from aspnet. An unfortunate roadblck for me has been around Odata in general, one of the concessions I was forced to make was moving a few routes to OData, as a mixture of OData and standard API wasnt compatible with swagger.

Anyhow, One such method (The last one remaining) has the following Signature

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostChanges([FromBody] ICollection<BulkEditDTO> changeSet)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var error = ModelState.Values.Select(x => x.Errors).FirstOrDefault();
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //TODO:Get data?

    }
```

Object

```
public class BulkEditDTO
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SomeDTO Changes { get; set; }
}
```

Now I feel like I've tried every combination of Functions, complex types, actions, ODataActionParamaers that i can think of - but i cannot seem to solve this. I even tried a simple DTO that has the ienumerable as a property, but that ran into problems with 'needing a key'.

A lot of the research i've tried leads me down to this path:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1873

That isnt quite the same, becuase thats looking for a header and Im trying to use a body.

Is there an actual workaround to this?

Comment: I have reproduced your issue.It seems that Odata could not receive List Model.A workaround is that you could put the list model to the other model and then you could receive it.

Comment: I tried to create BulkEditCollectionDTO, with a single iEnumerable property, but then I got an error about not having a model with a key, is that what you are suggesting @Rena? Were you able to make that work?

Comment: Yes,it is.I could only get this workaround to add a model with `Id` and `ICollection<BulkEditDTO>`.It would get the FromBody data successfully.

Comment: @Rena So you made up a fake key to trick Odata?

Just to confirm.

Comment: Yes.May be you could try to do a research for odata source code to check if it has any other solution.